# What Kavacha's are being read in the attached video by Sachidananda swamy?

Tags: shiva, ganesha

Namaste!

Does any of you know which Ganesha Kavacham is being read by Sri Ganapati Sachchidananda Swamy  in his Kavacha Manjari?

I found the Shiva Kavacham on sanskritdocuments.org but I'm unable to find the Ganesha Kavacham, there seems to be multiple Kavacha's for Ganesha. It'll be great if any of you can provide me with the pdflinks for other Kavacha's also including the Ganesha Kavacha

Link to the video of "Six Divine Kavachams by Sri Ganapati Sachchidananda Swamy with Timestamps" is  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xvj46-M1kIs

Comment: The link is nonexistent